# Resolver for inner-nested object in storio

Tags: android, storio

tell me please, how write resolver for inner-nested object in storio. example

```
"book": {"id": 1, "title": "The Chronicles of Amber", "author": "Roger Zelazny", "reader": {"id": 1, "name": "Jack"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have 2 different approaches:

1. Store nested object in same table
2. Store nested object in separate table

If you go with option 1 then you just need to add composed type like `TweetWithUser`/etc and write operation resolvers that will parse different objects separately and create composed type. Example [is here](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio/blob/671ef497fe6b56a1dbe60a94f5855dbff02d749a/storio-sample-app/src/main/java/com/pushtorefresh/storio/sample/db/resolvers/TweetWithUserGetResolver.java).

If you go with option 2 then it's pretty much the same approach of getting separate objects from `Cursor` as 1 but you'll need to pass custom `RawQuery` with `JOIN` to get both objects.

We have an example of that in the [sample app in the repo](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio/tree/671ef497fe6b56a1dbe60a94f5855dbff02d749a/storio-sample-app), please check it!

Personally, we've used second option in real apps with StorIO, works ok.

---

Just always keep in mind that StorIO is not ORM and you have full control over both queries and operations resolvers, also you can pass specific operation resolver per query.